# Syntax error when trying to run code from VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to run some code in my VS Code terminal and when I click on `Run active file` I get this syntax error message

```
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 5: `const addTwoNums = (numbers, k) => {'
```

This is the code I'm trying to run so I know there isn't a syntax error. If I try and run the same function in my browser console it works correctly. I'm running VSCode on a Mac.

```
const addTwoNums = (numbers, k) => {
    let left = 0;
    let right = numbers.length - 1;

    while (left < right) {
        const sum = numbers[left] + numbers[right];
        if (sum === k) {
            return true;
        } else if (left < k) {
            left += 1;
        } else {
            right -= 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

addTwoNums([10, 15, 3, 7], 17);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This tells the shell to run the script with `node`.

Comment: So that fixed the syntax error but now I get nothing returned back in the terminal.

Comment: Add `console.log`, so `console.log(addTwoNums([10, 15, 3, 7], 17));`